# Vaadin 14 TreeGrid - Grid not loading hierarchy

Tags: java, vaadin

I am writing an application which will display information logically represented as a collection of hierarchies of items. There will be a "top-level" list that will display the names of all the root nodes in the collection. When one of the items is selected, another list (the tree grid) will be loaded with the selected root node and I need it to display and provide access to everything in its hierarchy.

I can't figure out how to get the hierarchy to load in the grid.

I have defined a data provider class that extends `AbstractBackEndHierarchicalDataProvider`. It is my impression that the purpose of this class is to facilitate retrieving data in a hierarchical relationship. I also have a `@Service` class that is called from the provider to do the work. The class (`TaskMaster`) that represents the nodes does not contain any references to a "parent" or "children".

Here is the code:

TaskTreeView.java

```
public class TaskTreeView extends VerticalLayout {
  private TreeGrid<TaskMaster>   taskGrid;
  private TaskMasterDataProvider provider;
  private TaskMasterService      taskService;

  public TaskTreeView(TaskMasterService taskService) {
    this.taskService = taskService;
  }

  // Load the selected task (and its hierarchy).
  public void loadTasks(TopLevelTaskView.TaskSelectionEvent event) {
    if (event.getSelected() != null) {
      updateTree(event.getSelected());
    }
  }

  private void updateTree(TaskMaster task) {
    taskGrid.setItems(task);
    provider.refreshItem(task, true);
  }

  private void configureView() {
    taskGrid = new TreeGrid<>(TaskMaster.class);
    taskGrid.setColumns("name", "type");
    taskGrid.setHierarchyColumn("name");
    taskGrid.getColumns().forEach(col -> {
      col.setAutoWidth(true);
      col.setResizable(true);
    });

    provider = new TaskMasterDataProvider(taskService);
    taskGrid.setDataProvider(provider);
    add(taskGrid);
  }
}
```

TaskMasterDataProvider.java

```
public class TaskMasterDataProvider
    extends AbstractBackEndHierarchicalDataProvider<TaskMaster, Void> {
  private TaskMasterService service;

  public TaskMasterDataProvider(TaskMasterService service) {
    this.service = service;
  }

  @Override
  public int getChildCount(HierarchicalQuery<TaskMaster, Void> query) {
    return service.getChildCount(query.getParent());
  }

  @Override
  public boolean hasChildren(TaskMaster item) {
    return service.hasChildren(item);
  }

  @Override
  protected Stream<TaskMaster> fetchChildrenFromBackEnd(HierarchicalQuery<TaskMaster, Void> query) {
    return service.getChildren(query.getParent()).stream();
  }
}
```

TaskMasterService.java

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class TaskMasterService {
  private final TaskMasterRepository    taskMasterRepo;
  private final TaskRelationshipService taskRelationService;

  @Autowired
  public TaskMasterService(TaskMasterRepository taskMasterRepo,
      TaskRelationshipService taskRelationService) {
    this.taskMasterRepo = taskMasterRepo;
    this.taskRelationService = taskRelationService;
  }

  ...
  
  public int getChildCount(TaskMaster parent) {
    return parent != null
        ? taskRelationService.getChildRelationsForParent(parent.getInternalTaskID()).size()
        : 0;
  }

  public boolean hasChildren(TaskMaster parent) {
    return parent != null
        ? !taskRelationService.getChildRelationsForParent(parent.getInternalTaskID()).isEmpty()
        : false;
  }

  public List<TaskMaster> getChildren(TaskMaster parent) {
    List<TaskMaster> result = new ArrayList<>();

    if (parent != null) {
      List<TaskRelationship> childRelations = taskRelationService
          .getChildRelationsForParent(parent.getInternalTaskID());

      childRelations.forEach(relation -> {
        result.add(taskMasterRepo.findByInternalTaskID(relation.getChildTaskID()));
      });
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

When I run the application and select an item from the "top level" list, the tree loads the root node and nothing else. Am I using the provider in the wrong way?

Domain data explanation (as best as I understand it):

**TaskMaster**

Contains information about "tasks", which is a broad description for a number of things, but is mainly used to define an application menu structure. The task type is one of the following: TASK_VIEW, INTERACTIVE, BATCH, FOLDER, URL, USER_DEFINED. The unique ID is internalTaskID. Note that this is NOT the database key. **There is no concept of a "parent" or "children" in this data structure.**

**TaskRelationship**

Contains a parent/child relationship between two "tasks" (i.e. TaskMaster entities).

Example:

In TaskMaster:

```
{
    internalTaskID: "1014",
    name: "Manufacturing Tasks",
    type: "00", // TASK_VIEW
}

{
    internalTaskID: "464E4534",
    name: "Manufacturing Inquiries",
    type: "07", // FOLDER
}

{
    internalTaskID: "4E3CBF33",
    name: "Item Ledger",
    type: "01", // INTERACTIVE
}
```

In TaskRelationship:

```
{
    parentTaskID: "1014",
    childTaskID: "464E4534",
}

{
    parentTaskID: "464E4534",
    childTaskID: "4E3CBF33",
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example (for example on GitHub) that I can try it out? I assume that getChildCount is wrong as you return 0 if the parent is null but the item with parent == null is the root element and has children for sure

Comment: I have added the project to github. Try https://github.com/jgagnon44/e1-task-info-alt.git.

Comment: It's multi-module Maven. You might need to do a little work to get some data in the database.

Comment: Your project does not compile. com.fossfloors:excel-to-json:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. I've added the other project to github. https://github.com/jgagnon44/excel-to-json.git

Comment: Have you checked my answer?

Comment: Yes. I think I understand what you're getting at, but not sure how that works with what I have. With debug statements in place, the getChildCount() is called a total of 3 times up front and then never again. The other provider methods are never called.

Comment: Yes because you return 3 times 0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228643/discussion-between-joseph-gagnon-and-simon-martinelli).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem are these methods:

```
  public int getChildCount(TaskMaster parent) {
    return parent != null
        ? taskRelationService.getChildRelationsForParent(parent.getInternalTaskID()).size()
        : 0;
  }

  public boolean hasChildren(TaskMaster parent) {
    return parent != null
        ? !taskRelationService.getChildRelationsForParent(parent.getInternalTaskID()).isEmpty()
        : false;
  }
```

If you are on the root element of your tree the parent is always null. In that case you don't have to return false or 0.

In the case you are on the root element that has not parent you have to return true in the method `hasChildren` and the number of children of the root element in `getChildCount`

Comment: The problem with this is that the only time the `getChildCount()` method is called, the passed in parent is always null. I can't get the number of children of something that doesn't exist. None of the other methods are ever called. Why? Can someone explain how this thing is supposed to work and be used?

Comment: If the passed in parent is null, you are not supposed to return 0. In this case you should return the total number of root items. So you can write another method in your service, something like `int countAllRootTasks()` and return the value, instead of returning 0.